# Datatype of Keys and Values of IReadOnlyDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, interface

For `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the `Keys` and `Values` properties are of type `ICollection<TKey>` and `ICollection<TValue>`.

For `IReadonlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the `Keys` and `Values` properties are of type `IEnumerable<TKey>` and `IEnumerable<Value>`.

Why aren't the properties of `IReadonlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` just the corresponding ReadOnly interfaces, namely `IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>` and `IReadOnlyCollection<TValue>`?

One might wonder why both properties aren't of type `IEnumerable` as you can't alter the dictionary through the two properties but through `Add` and `Remove` methods. In fact the `ICollection` returned by `IDictionary.Keys` has the `IsReadOnly` property set, so tried to invoke `Add` or `Remove` on the property throws an `NotSupportedException` with the additional information *Mutating a key collection derived from a dictionary is not allowed.*

If one anyways can't alter the dictionary through its properties, why aren't the both `IReadOnlyCollections`?
The `IReadOnly` interfaces was first introduced in .NET 4.5, so I guess that can't be done without an undesired breakage of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It puts less of a burden on people implementing a custom `IReadonlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>` if they did not want to use things that derived from `IReadOnlyCollection` for their backing stores.

If you are using the built in implementation of `ReadOnlyDictionary` there is nothing stopping you from casting the interface.

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<Foo, Bar> baz = GetDictionary();

IEnumerable<Foo> keys = baz.Keys;
IReadOnlyCollection<Foo> keysCollection = keys as IReadOnlyCollection<Foo>;

if(keysCollection != null)
{
    //This code will execute for the built in implmentation of `ReadOnlyDictionary<Foo, Bar>`
}
```

Comment: This is a bit obtuse.  Are you saying that it's easier, more common and more understandable to create a Keys collection or a Values collection that's enumerable without having to cast `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`?  Because I could get on board with that.

Comment: `ICollection<T>` inherits from both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`.  The designers of the newer `IReadOnlyCollection` apparently felt they no longer needed the composite interface, and could just inherit from`IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` directly.

Comment: But `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` does also inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, or are you saying they felt it was not necessary for `ICollection<T>` to also inherit `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think I misread the question.  It's apparently about the Key and Value collections not being *designated as read-only by declaring them as such.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey and Scott: I'm sorry if I my question was unclear, please see my edited question.

Comment: @JonasNyrup: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You don't modify either the collection of keys or the collection of values through the `Keys` and `Values` properties. You only use those properties to access the keys and values. So it doesn't matter whether or not they are explicitly read-only collections.

The keys and values can only be modified by adding items to the dictionary, which you can't do with an `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

Also, using an `ICollection` places an additional restriction on how a particular implementation of `IReadOnlyDictionary` returns those properties. An `IEnumerable<T>` can be implemented in many more ways, even by a method using a `yield` statement. If the returned type is `ICollection<T>` then the dictionary would be forced to populate something that implements `ICollection<T>`. It might still do that, but if something implements `ICollection<T>` then it also implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

So I'd wonder the other way - why does an `IDictionary<T>` return `ICollection<T>` for those properties instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. (There might be a good reason. But now I'm wondering.)

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable<T>` allows you to take advantage of Linq methods and the whole iterator infrastructure *directly,* without having to perform a cast.

You can't modify the data in the underlying `ReadOnlyDictionary` implementation anyway, even through the `Key` and `Value` collections.  `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't care whether its underlying implementation is read-only or not.

Comment: As `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` it should, to my knowledge, be able to use the same Linq methods?

Both of these two interfaces hides the `Add()`, `Remove()` and `Clear()` methods that `ICollection` has which makes no sense here, as the `Keys` and `Values` properties are readonly as you also mention.
Unless `Keys` or `Values` can be a lazily generated, it seems to me that using `IEnumerable<T>` is just an unnecessary generalization, that could lead you to think that the properties *could* be lazy or not already in memory.

Comment: Counter-question: what benefits would accrue by using `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for the Key and Value collections?

Comment: That I can reason about whether the underlying collection is eager or lazy.

Comment: But since `IReadOnlyCollection` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, it already inherits `IEnumerable<T>`'s semantics, including its laziness.

Comment: I'm here for finding out whether the dictionary IEnumerable values are lazily loaded and share @JonasNyrup's concerns (I did a toy test in LinqPad and think they are safely not re-evaluated). Also I don't think that inheritors of IEnumerable do inherit their laziness - I thought they did too, but not so (the clue is in how Count is implemented, having a Count property signals non-laziness)